# Unable to find Entry Point while using C++ dll in C# application

Tags: c#, c++

I have written a C# application which needs to call a function in a C++ dll on a button click. But on cllicking the button, it throws 'EntryPointNotFound' Exception.

```
Below is the code snippet of C#
    public class Test
    {
        [DllImport("Demo.dll", EntryPoint = "OpenFile"]
        public static extern bool OpenFile(string fileName);
    }
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool check = Test.OpenFile("test.txt"); // exception thrown at this point
            if (check)
            {
                // Not entering this area.. 
            }
        }


C++ Header (.h file)

__declspec(dllexport) bool OpenFile(CString fileName);

Cpp class (.cpp )
__declspec(dllexport) bool Demo::OpenFile(CString fileName)
{
        return true;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Check the exports table of the DLL you're using. I suspect you're running into name-mangling issues (even though it's a free-function).

Comment: Also, use the correct `[MarshalAs]` attributes. The CLR doesn't know that `fileName` is a `CString` instead of `char*` or `std::string`. The same applies for the return value, by default .NET `Boolean` is marshalled as Win32 `BOOL` instead of C++ `bool`.

Comment: You also can't p/invoke a CString.  You'll have to change your method to take a char* or wchar*.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618130/pinvoke-with-a-cstring

Comment: I changed the entry point as the function name found in DependencyWalker. Added a function without any paramters. That worked.!!! But it is displays {"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."} when using string as parameter. I changed the C++ method parameter to char*. But still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to add extern "C" to the dll code:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool OpenFile(CString fileName);
```

Also see
[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892271/entrypointnotfoundexception-when-binding-c-dll-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I used the below code :                                                                        extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool OpenFile(CString fileName); But still doesn't worked